# how can i export IntOrString from dhall kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dhall

i want to import : `IntOrString` from dhall kubernetes,
https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/blob/master/1.19/types/io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.util.intstr.IntOrString.dhall;
but i don't know how to import it?,

i have this code :

```
let kubernetes =
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/master/package.dhall
let Prelude =https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/package.dhall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either import it directly:

```
let IntOrString = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/master/1.19/types/io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.util.intstr.IntOrString.dhall

…
```

… or access it as a field of the `kubernetes` package:

```
let kubernetes =
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/master/package.dhall

in  kubernetes.IntOrString
```